# Right click on link child doesn't show expected behavior in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have some links with font big awesome icons in page. IE9 doesn't show expected behavior. Usually right-click on a normal  link should open context menu with **Open in new tab**, but when clicked on the font awesome icon, context menu doensn't appear to be the right one. Refer the image for illustration.

Code: HTML

```
<a href="#" >
   <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
   <span>Link 1</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
     a {
        display: inline-table;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 7px;
        height: 100px;
        color: #580f8b;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
     }
    a i {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        line-height: 48x;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    i:before {
       font-size: 36px; 
    }
    a span {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 12px; 
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Link to [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3PCe/18/)

[image]

Comment: This looks like a z-index issue. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, fiddle link is there in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/q3PCe/19/

Its Because of ".window_label" Class is written with position:absolute
add z-index for Anchor tag

```
     a {
  z-index:5;
   }
```

Comment: This is IE9 specific issue. Adding x-index doesn't fix it :(